# fatal error no such file or directory

Tags: terminal, compiling, gcc

Hi i have a problem in linux terminal line. So i tried compiling a file to .o like this

```
gcc -c palindrome.c
```

and the error is

```
palindrome.c:2:21: fatal error: reverse.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The file reverse.h indeed is in the directory because i copied everything from lab2 directory to lab 3. So why is it saying that? Thanks for the help

```
cscstuff@ubuntu:~/inlab2$ ls -l
total 32
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cscstuff cscstuff 8784 Oct  1 08:26 main1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff  338 Oct  1 08:20 main1.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff 1888 Oct  1 08:24 main1.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff  204 Oct  1 08:26 reverse.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff   84 Oct  1 08:19 reverse.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff 1472 Oct  1 08:26 reverse.o
cscstuff@ubuntu:~/inlab2$ cd
cscstuff@ubuntu:~$ cd inlab3
cscstuff@ubuntu:~/inlab3$ ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 cscstuff cscstuff 4096 Oct  1 08:33 inlab2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff  247 Oct  1 09:21 main2.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff  297 Oct 15 11:01 palindrome.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cscstuff cscstuff   51 Oct  1 08:34 palindrome.h
cscstuff@ubuntu:~/inlab3$ gcc -c palindrome.c
palindrome.c:2:21: fatal error: reverse.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cscstuff@ubuntu:~/inlab3$
```

Comment: Which directory **exactly** are you in when you are run the gcc command? You appear to have a very confusing directory layout - with an `inlab3` subdirectory *inside* `~/inlab2` - and both `inlab2` and `inlab3` subdirectories inside `~/inlab3`

Comment: i am in lab3 when im running the command let me try deleting the extra lab3 sub directory inside lab3. also the lab3 directory is not suppose to be in lab2 directory. mistake on my part

Comment: i updated my stuff so its less confusing but it still giving me the same errors

Comment: What is your include line for the reverse.h in your c file?

Comment: it does not have an include line. Is that the problem?

Comment: Of course there's an include line. Otherwise we wouldn't be having this discussion

Comment: You know, it's very hard to suggest a solution when we have to guess at the code causing the problem. Chance of seeing a **cut-down** sample that is self-contained but that still exhibits the problem please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `inlab3` either

- add `-I../inlab2` to compiler (e.g. `gcc -I../inlab2 -c palindrome.c`, this will tell gcc to look in ../inlab2 for the header file)
- use `#include "../inlab2/reverse.h"` in include line (this will give relative path for the header file)
- copy from `inlab2` `cp ../inlab2/reverse.h .` (this will make a copy of the header file available in `inlab3`)